# Django perform Annotate , count and Compare

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have following Model.

```
class Gallery(BaseModel):
    company = models.ForeignKey(to=Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=upload_company_image_to,
        validators=[validate_image]
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.company.name}'
```

I want to allow maximum upto 5 image to be uploaded by one company so I tried my query as

```
def clean(self):
    print(Gallery.objects.values('company').annotate(Count('image')).count())
```

I don't know how to compare above query with Integer 5. How do I do that?

Comment: What Django version do you use?

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the `Company`s that have more than five images with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

Company.objects.alias(
    num_images=Count('gallery')
).filter(num_images__gt=5)
```

Prior to [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2), you can work with [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate):

```
from django.db.models import Count

Company.objects.annotate(
    num_images=Count('gallery')
).filter(num_images__gt=5)
```

Comment: Thank you for the query how do I restrict such that if count is greater than 5 there must be Validation Error?

Comment: @daneilJames: you should validate this in the form or view where you create `Company`s, since a Django model itself only can validate its columns, not the many-to-many field that is populated.

Comment: I want to validate from admin side of django admin panel

Comment: @daneilJames: than you need to modify the `ModelAdmin` that works with that model.

Comment: ```if Gallery.objects.values('company').annotate(Count('image')).filter(image__count__gte=10).count()``` did this way how efiicent will this be?

Comment: @daneilJames: but then you count the number of companies with more than 10 images.